# How to set GPOS in iText 7 for thailand double mark above the letter

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I need advice how to set GPOS in iText 7 for Thailand double mark above the letter.

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
PdfFont fontLoad = PdfFontFactory.createFont(font, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
form.getField("Text1").setValue("ตั้", fontLoad,20);
form.flattenFields();
pdf.close();
```

Actual Result

[image: Actual Result]

Expected result

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that extra positioning/interaction (see: [ligatures](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/signs-and-symbols/ligatures-1)) information from the font file, you would need [pdfCalligraph](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph), an iText 7 Core add-on.

Without pdfCalligraph, I get:

[image]

where with pdfCalligraph, I get:

[image]

Which I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: I use AngsanaNew-Bold.ttf

Comment: @Encep, just updated the answer using the font you want to use